# Unique alpha-numeric string from a unique integer? (masking IDs in a game server?)

Tags: web-services

I have a multiplayer mobile game out in the wild, it's backed by a sql database. Each game gets an ID which is just an auto-increment field. I can look up a game with a url like:

```
http://www.example.com/gameId=123
```

That url is not visible to players at the moment, but I was thinking of displaying it so users can invite friends and let non-players look on in the game as they play (through a browser - at the moment everyone plays through a native app).

But the fact that I'm putting the game ID out there in the open seems like a bad idea. If someone guessed an endpoint for say deleting a game, they could do bad stuff knowing the ID  (of course my endpoints are protected by user auth, but still).

Do most services mask IDs of this sort, should I send out a url like:

```
http://www.example.com/gameId=maskedIdAbc
```

and then my game server has to translate that ID into the corresponding ID in my database?

Not sure if that's overkill. If not, what's a good way to generate a unique alpha-numeric string based off a unique integer?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into hash functions?  That's what immediately springs to mind.  At the same time, an attacker could deduce that you are using a hash function, especially if they see this :D so perhaps look into salting it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not change the primary key of the game from an incremental ID to a GUID?  The game is out in the wild but you should be able to get there in a number of steps.  Add the Guid as a Field and allow games to be looked up either by ID or GUID.  Update your clients to use the GUID, phase out the ID, and finally change the primary key to be the GUID.

You could hash the int, or even use the hex, but its breakable.  Better to implement a complete fix, if you don't want to use a GUID you could implement your equivalent random characters that you store against each db record but why go to the trouble when GUIDs are usually Nativity supported by databases.

Answer (score 0):

If range of the integers is not big, you may define tabble with unique, random alpha-num strings. I think it's the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I has a similar situation and did not want to use the gameID (using your example here) in the url, as someone can use any number. I can still use the ID's, but need to add additional checking for authorizing the users.

You could use UUID to generate gameID's but I see few problems with this;
- non numeric ID will have an impact on the performance
- if this is the primary key and want to use it as FK on other tables, space

What I did;
In addition to gameID in my table, I added another column WebGameID varchar (32). After the game ID was generated, updated the WebGameID = MD5(gameID). This will be a unique 32 char string for the specific gameID. With this I was able to use gameID for internal keys and FK's ad only use WebGameID for the URL for limiting user manipulation.